# Implement the method "plus"

Tags: scala

I'm implementing a plus method that should work this way:

> ```
> 1 plus 2      // 3
> "a" plus "b"  // "a and b = ab"
> ```

Here is my implementation:

```
object MyMath {
  implicit class MyMath(a: Any) {
    def plus(b: Any) = {
      (a, b) match {
        case (s: String, s2: String) => s"$s and $s2"
        case(i: Int, i2: Int) => i + i2
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(1 plus 2)
    println("a" plus "b")
  }
}
```

Should I avoid using type `Any`? Is this a sign of a code smell if I use `Any` too much?

Comment: Oh, you're using [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html), introduced in Scala 2.10.0.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I haven't specify the version but the string interpolation is not important here. That can be replaced by:   s1 + " and " + s2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off: Apologies for the shortness of this review. There's not much code, after all.

You've got a bit of inconsistent style with whitespace after your `case`s -- I haven't done Scala in a while, but if I'm remembering right, you're supposed to have a space after.

I'd recommend renaming `i` and `s` to `i1` and `s1`, respectively, just to be consistent.

Your 'spec' says that `"a" plus "b"` should return `"a and b = ab"`, but it actually returns `"a and b"`. Personally, I think it should return `"ab"`, a la string concatenation.

Using `Any` is not a code smell, though some error throwing may be in order if any types other than `Int` or `String` are used, so that if I call `1.0 plus "a"`, I don't just get nothing. It's up to you which type to use, though personally I'd use an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Aside from that, it looks good! Well done.

Answer (score 3):

This code will throw if you supply arguments of type that is different than any of case branches. If you use match there always has to be a branch to catch everything (or branches has to cover any possible type), much like switch { default: } in C++. It's not required by language (though scalac will produce warning), but sort of smelly code.

Answer (score 1):

this is a possible  implementation without Any ,I hope it helpful

```
trait Plus[T]{

  def plus(el :T):T

}

object Plus{

  implicit class PlusInt(d:Int) extends  Plus[Int] {
    override def plus(el: Int): Int = d + el
  }

  implicit class PlusString(d:String) extends  Plus[String] {
    override def plus(el: String): String = d + el
  }

}
```

this is the test

```
class PlusTest extends FunSuite  {

  import Plus._

  test("test") {

    assert(2 === (1 plus 1))
    assert("ab" === ("a" plus "b"))
  }

}
```

This solution in my opinion improves the other one because, if you don't implement for a class, the code will not compile, instead of throwing a runtime exception (MatchError).

Comment: Reviews should always include *explanation*, not simply an alternate implementation. One of the main points of this site is learning both how and why to do things "better".